# What is a "skin shard"?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently received a "skin shard" when opening my free chest in League of Legends.

I thought it gave me a free skin, but that appears not to be the case. What is a "skin shard" in league of legends and what is it good for?

Comment: I haven't read up on this stuff since it's initial intro, but I think shards can be used on their own to temporarily unlock that skin, or combined to permanently unlock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are part of a new [system](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/2016-season-update/champion-mastery.html) Riot is implementing. They can be combined via Hextech Crafting to permanently unlock skins. Champion shards are used for unlocking champions and skin shards for skins. If you have a skin shard, you can either reroll it with 2 other skin shards (can be different skin shards) or skin permanents to get another skin permanent (guaranteed to be a non-dup of one you own) or you can upgrade it with essence (price may vary between skins, depending on rp price) to a skin permanent. The same applies to champion shards. You can also use a skin shard to temporarily unlock the skin. It will last 7 days.

Comment: So if I get 3 of the same shard, I can unlock a skin? Or what?

Comment: @GarrettJ that's how it was when I used it on the PBE. I will double check again on the PBE when I get some free time.

Comment: @GarrettJ see updates

Comment: Also you get the essence by disenchanting skin shards or other cosmetic item's shards and different price categories of skins have different essence requirements, an ultimate skin takes like 5000ish essence or did on PBE anyways.

Comment: You don't have to have 3 identical skin shards, you just have to get 1 skin shard and however many Essence you need to convert it into a permanent skin. Usually, 4 skin shards converted into essence should be enough to get you 1 permanent skin (depending on the RP price of the shard)

Comment: Note that it does not cost a set amount of essence for everything. Cheaper RP skins will cost less essence, its believed essence cost is directly proportional to RP cost, usually a percentage (like 80% or something)

Comment: @Ryan thnx for the correction. i was testing it on the PBE server and the only skins i had gotten were 675.

Comment: One ultimate skin converted to essence will give you two or three regular skins worth of essence, I bought like 100 on PBE to see how it worked and I got an ultimate skin and like 3 or 4 legendary skins.